# visual studio settings for typescript intellisense and TS2307 (TS) Cannot find module Miscellaneous

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2019

The command `npm run build` successfully build the package and the app runs in browser just fine.
But the VS2019 keeps complaining with 
**Error TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module '...'.  Miscellaneous**.[image: tsconfig.json works fine]

Is there a setting in the IDE where some things should be changed to make the the VS as happy as the npm?

**EDIT**
Restart of the IDE resolved one line but not the other
 [image: the IDE is still not happy]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. There are settings in the project that might make the experience somewhat inconsistent.

VS uses project file (`.csproj`) and IDE default settings to configure typescript intellisence when the `tsconfig.json` file is not part of the project. The `npm run build` command (or similar CLI approach) on the other hand uses the `tsconfig.json` all the time.  This may lead to mixed experience. Indeed VS will show false hints and errors if particular settings differ in `.csproj` and in `tsconfig.json`.

Make sure tsconfig.json relates to the build process as **Content** (rather than **None**) yet never copied to the output directory. This way you force the IDE to detect your settings and use them.

[image: tsconfig.json must be a part of the project]

[image]

Comment: the tsconfig.json build action property change worked for me, but also required unloading/reloading the project to see it take effect in the editor and project properties page